# In Uno H2O, what is the difference between these two cards?

Tags: uno

Today I was playing Uno H2O and I found these two cards, but I'm not sure what is the difference between these?
One looks like a Wild Draw 4, but it doesn't have the +4 on it, so I'm confused about its purpose.

[image: Uno cards]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are both wild cards, just from two different printings.

The one on the left is the original 2004 design, and other from the end of 2005.
Matel updated the design for printing UNO H20 Splash, seemingly to avoid confusion with the Draw 4.